# Get user from token with laravel tymon/jwt-auth

Tags: php, laravel, tymon-jwt

I’m trying to get user from bearer token( tymon/jwt-auth) with laravel, were token is part of the request body not headers. How can I achieve this?.

Thanks.

Comment: try this $user = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->toUser();

Comment: In the personal i used `$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();` cause verified token is valid, https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication